# how to install mysqldumpslow on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, perl

I'm tring to install mysqldumpslow on windows, noticed that it is a perl script `mysqldumpslow.pl`.

I install Perl on windows and run `perl mysqldumpslow.pl` on cmd and it keep warning me: *Can't determine basedir from 'my_print_defaults mysqld'*

I'm sure that I've set the basedir in `my.ini` and restart the server, but nothing change.

if i use `perl mysqldumpslow.pl` + *my-mysql-slow-query-log*, it work. But i hope to use command `mysqldumpslow` directly just like other `.exe` file.

what should i do? should i trl to compile the `.pl` to `.exe` file?

Comment: I am assuming you are using windows. can you try `mysqldumpslow.pl -s c -t 10 C:\Somedirectory\somelogfile.log`

Comment: @User5422332 it works! Thx! (and seems I install starwberry perl instead of active perl, so that I can can run `.pl` file everywhere now). On more question, can I set a default path to my log file? (I noticed that  `mysqldumpslow` will check the `*-slow.log` file from a specific path by default in linux)